# Can i fit a 2x5 pin crimp connector on the raspberry pi pins?

Tags: gpio, connectors

Do smaller than 2x13 or 2x20 pin crimp connectors (depending on raspberry model), like a 2x5 pin connector, normally fit on the raspberrys pins or will the edges of the connector take too much room?

This connector can be used as an example https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10650.

For my project I only need some the eight first pins. The alternative is of course to have a full size connector and use a smaller ribbon cable.

Comment: You can, yes. But then edges won't fit in. So you have to get rid of two pin on top and bottom if you're connecting it somewhere around the middle part, take pin 11 - 20 for example. If at top (pin 1 - 10), you will still lose bottom two pins (11-12) and same goes for bottom most part (say, pin 31 - 40 for Rpi2) losing pin (29-30).

Comment: Ok, so I need a full size connector and use a smaller cable then. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is probably the right solution.

Comment: If you get jumper leads that come as tear-aways with individual female connectors, you can glue the connectors together into a 2 * 4 plug.  Can't find any on sparkfun but **[this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10374)** is the same idea only better, since you only have to glue two of them together.

Comment: @goldilocks That's a really good solution. I found these on ebay (http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/272001358543 for the housing and these http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/291577311179 as crimp pin connectors). Hope I used correct terms for the stuff there.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the style of connector.

The IDC connectors which go on ribbon cable (like the one you linked) unfortunately have rather wide sides and will only fit on a standard pin header if they cover it completely.

On the other hand the connectors where you crimp individual pins and then insert them into a housing have much narrower sides and will fit fine onto part of a pin header.

You can also use "stacking" style connectors intended for PCB mounting to space an IDC connector off the board.